# Armature Deform With Automated Weights only on selected bones

Tags: rigging

:)

How can i use *Armature Deform With Automated Weights* while Blender only considers some bones of the armature and not all of them?

In my case i only want to use the two selected bones while the other ones that controll the eyes are completely ignored.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find that option in weight paint mode.
[image]